# Running all SSRS reports through one report user ignoring own users domain

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have the following code which returns the reports from my SSRS server, afterwards I then store the paths to each individual list which allows users to run them from within the application. *The below works fine.*

```
NetworkCredential serviceCredentials = new NetworkCredential()
{
     UserName = username,
     SecurePassword = EncryptionManager.DecryptToSecureString(password),
     Domain = domain
};

reports = new ObservableCollection<object>(reportsManager.FindReports(reportsWebService, reportsFolderName, serviceCredentials));



//FindReports
ReportingService2005 rs = new ReportingService2005();
rs.Url = reportsWebService;
rs.Credentials = serviceCredentials;

CatalogItem[] catalogItems = rs.ListChildren(@"/" + reportsFolderName, false);
```

However the problem is when a user selects a report to view it shows the following error:

> The permissions granted to user are insufficient for performing this
>   operation.

I understand that the quick fix to this would be to add the users domain into the security section on the Report server, however this is not appropriate.

My question is I can supply credentials to allows a specified user to access the report folder is it possible to pass this along so that user can run a report?

Each of my reports use built in connection strings **NOT** windows authentication.

**Edit:**  I am using Reporting WinForms.

Comment: I'm thinking that the ASPNet User or the IUser account needs to be added to the Report Server to allow access.

Comment: The user I am passing through in the network credential is added on the report server however the user who is attempting to connect is not added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Windows Forms

In a windows forms project you can pass a suitable [`System.Net.NetworkCredential`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential(v=vs.110).aspx) to [`ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportservercredentials.networkcredentials(v=vs.100).aspx) property of `ReportViewer`. This way, all reports will be executed using the passed credential:

```
reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials =
    new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
```

### Web Forms

The solution for a Web Forms is different. In a Web Forms project, to pass a suitable credential to `RePortViewer` you need to implement [`IReportServerCredentials`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.ireportservercredentials.aspx). Then you can assign the value to [`ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.serverreport.reportservercredentials.aspx) property of `ReportViewer` control. This way, all reports will be executed using the passed credential.

**Example**

Here is a simple implementation. It's better to store username, password and domain name in app config and read them from config file:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Principal;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;
[Serializable]
public sealed class MyReportServerCredentials : IReportServerCredentials
{
    public WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser { get { return null; } }
    public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
    {
        get
        {
            return new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
        }
    }
    public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string userName,
        out string password, out string authority)
    {
        authCookie = null;
        userName = password = authority = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then in `Page_Load` pass the credential this way:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
        this.ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = 
            new Sample.MyReportServerCredentials();
}
```

**Note**

In cases which you want to use `ReportViewer` with no session state you can also implement [`IReportServerConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.ireportserverconnection.aspx). In this case you need to add a key value in `appsettings` section of config file to introduce the implementation this way:

```
<add key="ReportViewerServerConnection" value="YourNameSpace.YourClass, YourAssemply" />
```

In this case, you don't need code in `Page_Load` and the config would be enough. For more information take a look at [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brianhartman/2008/11/21/custom-credentials-in-the-report-viewer/) great blog post by Brian Hartman.

Comment: Cheers, I think i get it, my main problem at the moment is testing it, may take a few to get a non admin domain account set up to run through.

Comment: No problem, let me know the result. I tested it from a system out of domain while the report server was joined in domain and it worked properly. Also in domain when the logged in domain user doesn't have sufficient permission, since we use `MyReportServerCredentials` it works properly. Just keep in mind, the user/password which you use for all reports should have access to reports.

Comment: When testing from a system which is not joined in the domain, make sure you clear probable credentials you saved previously in credentials store.

Comment: I have just been able to get an area to test this, the only difference is I am using Reporting win forms as opposed to web forms and ReportServerCredentials is read only

Comment: Thanks, although according to msdn documentation it should have a setter https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportservercredentials.networkcredentials(v=vs.100).aspx I will update the dll see if i can resolve it :)

Comment: I tested it with a windows forms project too. The windows forms solution is different. Check the edit.

Comment: nice! I'll give it a test now :)