# Using SQL Server Authentication to connect to SSRS from a WinForms Application

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, reporting-services, reporting

I'm busy testing SSRS to see if it's a viable alternative to our current reporting solution. I've set up SSRS on my local machine and have developed a working report using SQL Server Report Builder. Now what I'm trying to do is to call the report from within a WinForms application and display it in a ReportViewer control. The problem is that I've set up SQL Server to use SQL Server Authentication and I'm struggling to figure out how to connect to it programmatically.

The code I've pieced together so far looks like this:

```vb
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms

Public Class frmMain
Public v_report_name As String = "TestReport"
Public v_report_server As String = "http://elnah-ict-dt006:80"
Public v_report_path As String = "/reports_SSRS/"

Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'create parameter array
    Dim paramlist As New List(Of Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter)

    'create a specific parameter required by the report
    Dim param1 As New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("ClientID")

    'add values to the parameter here we use a variable that holds the parameter value
    param1.Values.Add("0279")

    'add parameter to array
    paramlist.Add(param1)

    'Set the processing mode for the ReportViewer to Remote  
    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote

    'use the serverreport property of the report viewer to select a report from a remote SSRS server
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New System.Uri(v_report_server)
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = v_report_path & v_report_name
    'select where the report should be generated with the report viewer control or on the report server using the SSRS service.
    'Me.ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Remote

    'add the parameterlist to the viewer
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(paramlist)


    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
End Class
```

When it hits the SetParameters line towards the bottom, it gets the following error message:

> Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.MissingEndpointException
>     HResult=0x80131500
>     Message=The attempt to connect to the report server failed.  Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.
>     Source=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms

I've tried to find examples of how to set the username and password but from what I can tell, most examples are focused on using Windows Authentication. I've tried the following line but it doesn't work:

```vb
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = New ReportServerCredentials("SA", "mypassword")
```

I haven't worked in VB.NET for ages so please excuse any obvious errors.

Comment: For future reference, please take a look at the edit I made to your question to make your VB code highlight correctly. You need that if VB.NET is not the first tag.

Comment: can you show us what your connection string looks like? Also, SQL Server Authentication have you set it to Mixed Mode or just SQL Logins?

Comment: Thanks for the tip jmcilhinney, I'll do that in future. @SimonPrice, I think I've set it up as mixed. If I look at the properties, Server Authentication is set to SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode. As far as a connection string goes, I don't have one. Not sure how to do that in this scenario? The examples I've seen online don't use one.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40725135/3110834).

Comment: @jmcilhinney I checked the source for the edit but just a bit ago I received the following comment. "Actually it should be either <!-- language: lang-vb --> or <!-- language: vb.net -->. lang-vb.net is not valid :). Though your first line was actually part of the list, however you had indented your other lines too much so they became a nested list under the first list. – Visual Vincent 12 hours ago " Now I am confused.

Comment: @Mary, the only edits I did here was adding `<!-- language: lang-vb -->`. If Vincent pointed out other issues in another post of yours elsewhere then they were unrelated.

Comment: @jmcilhinney No, I was using `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` Then Vincent said that was incorrect and I should use `<!-- language: vb.net -->.` No hyphen and not lang. Then I see you added the one with the hyphen (or is it a dash?) I am wondering which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code from a Web Forms project I was part of the team for recently:

```c#
private void SetCredentials()
{
    var userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSRSUserName"];
    var passwordEncrypted = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSRSUserPasswordEncrypted"];
    var passwordPlainText = SI.Crypto3.Crypto.Decrypt(passwordEncrypted, PASSPHRASE);
    var domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSRSUserDomain"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordPlainText) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain))
    {
        this.EventsHubReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportServerCredentials(userName, passwordPlainText, domain);
    }
}
```

That's C# but hopefully you can see that the important part is that last line.  I think that the equivalent in your case should be:

```vb
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = New ReportServerCredentials(userName, password, domain)
```

The `domain` value can be an empty `String` if your on the same domain as the server.

EDIT:

I looked more closely and the `ReportServerCredentials` class that code is using is one of our own.  In your case, you can use the `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.ReportServerCredentials` class, which I don't think has a constructor like that. Looking at the documentation for the `NetworkCredentials` property of that type indicates that you need to do this:

```vb
Dim credentials As New NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain)

ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials = credentials
```

Comment: I've added `Imports System.Configuration` but I can't seem to reference `ConfigurationManager`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need the `ConfigurationManager` class. Like I said, that was just an example of how we're doing it one of our applications and it was the last line that was of importance. You just create the `NetworkCredential` object and pass the user name, password and domain values. Where you get those values from is irrelevant to that part. In our case, we were storing them in the `<appSettings>` section of the web.config file but you shouldn't be doing that. Just retrieve those values from wherever you're storing them, e.g. `My.Settings` and then use the last code snippet.

Comment: Okay, this is embarrassing... just figured out that I was using the wrong URL for the report server. I didn't even need to provide the username and password as the server had been set up work with both Windows Authentication as well as SQL Server Authentication. In the end I used the following report server URL and report path:
`        serverReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri("http://elnah-ict-dt006/ReportServer_SSRS")
        serverReport.ReportPath = "/TestReport"`